# gamlss Error in while (abs(G.dev.old - G.dev) > c.crit && iter < n.cyc)

Tags: r, gamlss

I'v been working with this data

`year rango_edad Sexo zona_2016 conteo siniestros expuestos upc_millon valor_millon freq
1 2010    01. < 1    F   Alejada    180         87        75        121          111 0.48
2 2010    01. < 1    F  Ciudades 103453      76219     40228      60755        84981 0.74
3 2010    01. < 1    F  Especial   5129       3194      2078       3289         3013 0.62
4 2010    01. < 1    F    Normal  27393      18436     10735      15656        16692 0.67
5 2010    01. < 1    M   Alejada    185         98        73        116          110 0.53
6 2010    01. < 1    M  Ciudades 106915      80731     41719      62991       105135 0.76
  costo.medio ratio
1        1.27  0.92
2        1.11  1.40
3        0.94  0.92
4        0.91  1.07
5        1.12  0.94
6        1.30  1.67`

and I'm trying to model the frequency with gamlss

`gamlss(freq~Sexo+zona_2016+rango_edad,family=PO(mu.link = "log"),data=na.omit(subset(datos,is.na(freq)==FALSE )))`
`gamlss(freq~Sexo+zona_2016+rango_edad,family=NBI(mu.link = "log"),data=na.omit(subset(datos,is.na(freq)==FALSE )))`

but I received this error message

> `Error in while (abs(G.dev.old - G.dev) > c.crit && iter < n.cyc) { : 
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

The response variable is NOT a count but a frequency with values from 0 to 1.
An appropriate model for this response (target) variable is the beta distribution. Please try family=BE.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't make sense to use Poisson if the response is a proportion between 0 and 1. That being said, there seems to be a bug in gamlss that doesn't allow for fractional response values even if they are greater than 1.

Comment: In addition, Negative Binomial has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error and apparently it's caused by using fractional response values. E.g. in the code below case 1 is fine, but cases 2-4 fail:

```
resp1 <- rep(1, 6)
trt <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
ftd1 <- gamlss(resp1 ~ trt, family = PO(mu.link = "log"))
resp2 <- rep(0.0001, 6)
ftd2 <- gamlss(resp2 ~ trt, family = PO(mu.link = "log"))
resp3 <- resp1
resp3[6] <- 0.0001
ftd3 <- gamlss(resp3 ~ trt, family = PO(mu.link = "log"))
resp4 <- resp1
resp4[6] <- 1.75
ftd4 <- gamlss(resp4 ~ trt, family = PO(mu.link = "log"))
```

To answer your question directly, use glm() or glm2() until after gamlss developers fix that (I sent them a link to this post). However, as the other answer pointed out, if your response is a proportion between 0 and 1 it doesn't make sense to fit Poisson in the first place.